# "Unable to load the metadata" errors when loading a project

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm a newbie to xaml and I had made an application a long time ago. It is a small project, nothing fancy or difficult, it was my first xaml/wpf project and I had made it in just a week end. I retrieved the code recently. The application still builds and runs, but the designer doesn't load. There are errors in the xaml file.  I don't recall having these errors before. The first one of these errors is:

`Unable to load the metadata for assembly 'MyProject'. This assembly may have been downloaded from the web.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545.  The following error was encountered during load: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)  C:\visualStudioWorkspace\MyProject\MyProject\MainWindow.xaml    1   1   MyProject`

I tried to go to the url mentioned, but I didn't understand any of it. I didn't download it from the web. I don't know what a 'assembly' is. I tried going through a few random files in my project but none had this "unblock" button they're talking about in their respective files properties.

Then there's around 10 errors in the xaml, all of which are similar to this one:

`The type 'local:ClickSelectTextBox' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   C:\visualStudioWorkspace\MyProject\MyProject\MainWindow.xaml    351 22  MyProject`

What can I do to solve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: When you say you retrieved the code recently, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean I had it on another computer a long time ago, and I recently got the code out of that computer and into this one. I also recently installed visual studio in this new operating system.

Comment: By what means did you transfer it?  Email?  USB drive?  File share?

Comment: File share I think, I'm not sure anymore. How could I check, assuming it matters?

Comment: The reason I ask is because some types of files, if they come from another computer, can have security restrictions imposed on them, especially if emailed, etc.  Close Visual Studio, go through each file in the solution, including the .SLN file itself, and right click to open the properties dialog.  At the bottom you may see a button with the words "Unblock" on it.  Click that button and re-open the solution.

Comment: yes I already did that as I said in my post above, but I didn't find the words 'unblock' nowhere.

Comment: Above you said you did it for a few random files.  Have you touched every file, including anything in your bin/Debug and bin/Release folders?

Comment: Now I did, but I didn't find 'unblock' anywhere.

Comment: Are there any third-party libraries or DLLs you're using/referencing?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It was a really simple project. But it's not entirely impossible either though, because I had some help doing it and I don't remember exactly everything I did. How could I check that?

Answer (score 2):

Windows keeps track of whether files may have been downloaded from the web by creating 'alternate data streams' for these files.  For a file named `myfile.txt`, the information about where it came from will be stored in a data stream named `myfile.txt:Zone.Identifier:$DATA`.  To unblock `myfile.txt` and make Windows stop worrying about where you got the file from, you just have to delete this alternate data stream.

You can use the [Sysinternals Streams utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) to find and get rid of these alternate data streams.

Answer (score 0):

to delete the streams associated with files in your solution : 
 `c:\streams -s -d <path to your solution>`