# Designer not able to show XAML (the type 'local:... was not found)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml

My issue seems to be the exact same one as this question:
["Unable to load the metadata" errors when loading a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097979/unable-to-load-the-metadata-errors-when-loading-a-project)
But since it is not answered I will ask my own question.

I am using `Microsft Visual C# 2010 Express` to open a project. No errors at first but when I open an `xaml file` I get the following errors:

```
Error   4   The type 'local:IndexConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    MainWindow.xaml 19  26  AppInventoryMvvm
Error   5   The type 'local:EditResourceMultiParamConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   MainWindow.xaml 39  26  AppInventoryMvvm
Error   6   The type 'local:AddResourceMultiParamConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    MainWindow.xaml 54  26  AppInventoryMvvm
Error   7   The type 'local:IndexConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    MainWindow.xaml 96  30  AppInventoryMvvm
Error   8   The type 'local:IndexConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    MainWindow.xaml 112 30  AppInventoryMvvm
```

As you can see all the errors look the same and the code where it is complaining looks like this:

```
<local:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
```

Now I am using the exact same version of IDE together with SP and so on as my other colleagues, (I am also opening the exact same project as them) it is a total mystery to me why I can view the design! any ideas?

To see the exact errors and code, please see the screen dump below:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to compile the code and these are only design view errors?

Comment: @RohitVats, Yes. I can run the code without issues. It must be a designer issue. (the errors get shown when I press 'Reload the designer')

Comment: is there a yellow exclamation mark on any assembly that you are referencing (see References in project)?

Comment: @Jehof, No I have already checked!

Comment: Check that the converters you are using are not using any null object's properties or methods. Can you post your converter's code?

Comment: @Palak.Maheria, thanks for your suggestion. I have checked that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and answer my own question, it might help other people in the future.

After a long time searching I found out that:

> Visual Studio doesn't support loading files from unreliable locations.

I had copied the project to a network storage disk and it just would not work. 
*As soon as I copied the project to a local disk it started working.*